# Http Core to handle requests in Android

Tags: android, http, apache-httpcomponents

Does the server in the [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java) work in Android?

When I try to use the constructor,

```
HttpService(HttpProcessor processor, ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy, HttpResponseFactory responseFactory, HttpRequestHandlerResolver handlerResolver, HttpParams params)
```

Eclipse says constructor is not defined. Eclipse gives a quick fix to change the constructor as:

```
HttpService(HttpProcessor proc, ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy, HttpResponseFactory responseFactory)
```

How will I register the handler for my requests in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setHandlerResolver` method to set handler. [Link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpService.html#setHandlerResolver%28org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandlerResolver%29)